# error integrating Google Sign-In using php

Tags: google-signin, google-api-client

I am using google/apiclient v2.12 package for integrating Google Sign-In using php8.0
The authentication works correctly on my local system but it doesn't work on server. It fails to verify the IdToken. Here is the error

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given
> in xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 422
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: "kid" invalid, unable
> to lookup correct key in
> xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:434

Stack trace:

> #0
> xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php(125):
> Firebase\JWT\JWT::getKey('-----BEGIN PUBL...', 'f1338caxxxxxxxxxx...')
>
> #1 xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(106):
> Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode('eyJhbxxxxxxxx...', '-----BEGIN PUBL...',
> Array)
>
> #2 xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(813):
> Google\AccessToken\Verify->verifyIdToken('eyJhbxxxxxxxx...',
> '1063xxxxxxxxx-x...')
>
> #3 xxxxxxxxxxx/g.php(12):
> Google\Client->verifyIdToken('eyJhbxxxxxxxx...') #4 {main} thrown in
> xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 434

code for g.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$id_token = $_GET['id_token'];
$clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $clientId]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
print_r($payload);
?>
```

Need help fixing this.

Comment: Please share your code in g.php

Comment: added code for g.php

Answer (score 1):

This is working with google/apiclient v2.10.1
It appears to be a bug in google/apiclient v2.12

Comment: Just had the same problem, thanks for posting, helped me as well